# Ubuntu Tweak Updates every day. Is this correct?

Tags: update-manager, ppa, ubuntu-tweak

When I did a fresh install of 12.04 a few weeks ago I run the Update Manager every day.

Everyday Ubuntu Tweak gets updated. I wouldn't mind but nothing seems to change in the application.  The first few days I thought there was back-end stuff getting updated.  Is it possible for one application to have updates everyday (the version number is always the same), or maybe there is something wrong with the installation?   My current verson is 0.7.2.

**This is what I used when I originally installed it**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: Latest stable version is 0.7.1. That means you're using a development version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by reinstalling Ubuntu Tweak.

First remove the PPA and Ubuntu Tweak:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-tweak
```

Now readd the PPA and and then install Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: Not sure I did install the unstable PPA  (see the output below), but I am sure your solution is correct had i installed it. 
Warning:  "Could not find package list for PPA: ubuntu-tweak-testing ppa"

Comment: @StephenMyall Open Software Center, When Software Center launches, Click Edit> Software Sources. Click on other software tab and check which PPA of Ubuntu Tweak is there?

Comment: @SialBasharat ppa:launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise, however there were two the source code PPA was there as well (was this the source of my issue?

Comment: @StephenMyall Well that looks fine. Try to remove this PPA and ubuntu tweak and then reinstall. See if that helps.

Comment: @SialBasharat  Can you update your answer with the final solution then i will accept it.  So others can benefit without reading the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Well I dont think there is any problem with the installations.
With this version made for 12.04 and both being new can have frequent updates and bug fixes.
For e.g there is still a bug in the log in screen when log in sound is disabled from ubuntu tweak.
So such updates and bug fixes are expected when bothe the os version and the software versions are new...

But if you still feel just remove all files by using

sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak
and then remove the reppository via commandline or like this-

software center > edit >software sources >other software tab and remove the corresponding repository.

then run

sudo apt-get update.

after this is done repeat the installation steps you had used.
:)